# Regression analysis and how to assess the assumption of normality of Y

Tags: regression, residuals, normality-assumption

I was told that to assess normality of Y in a regression, it is better to look at the residuals, rather than the conditional distribution of Y for each given X.

My understanding is that both are linked, so if one is normally distributed the other would be too. So I can't quite figure out why it would be better to look at residuals. Would it be something to do with ease/simplicity rather than a mathematically superior way?

Many thanks!

Comment: If you assume that $y\sim\mathcal{N}\left(\mathbf{X\beta}, \sigma^2\right)$, then the residuals *are* the conditional distribution of y given X.

Comment: @generic That's not quite true, even when we generously understand "are" to mean "up to location." One way to see that is to observe that any two residuals are negatively correlated, whereas that's not true of the model itself.

Answer (score 1):

Think of this with a single predictor which only takes on two values (like sex) and suppose there is a huge sex difference (income). You might see the distribution of income given sex as normal but the distribution of income for both together will be bimodal.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! In your example is looking at income given sex equivalent to looking at conditional Y distribution for each different X, whereas looking at the residuals is both populations? If so, looking at the residuals is a better guide for normality of distribution, as it is taking into account both populations?

Comment: As generic_user stated above the residuals _are_ the distribution of y give X. I was giving a concrete example in case that was more readily understandable than the formula.